# How to partition active memory in Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted

How to partition active memory in Ubuntu ?

These are the details :- 
[image]

---

I want to make partition just like windows of this 465 GB harddisk. How can I make it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. You should use a live medium to repartition your current disk.